# How can I authenticate with code and not show a login prompt using Integrated Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to write a web app that redirects a user to a page that used Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). I do not want the user to be prompted with the following dialog:

[image]

But instead I want the application to authenticate the user redirect them to the page.

The URL I am trying reach is not connected to an Active Directory - it literally just uses Windows Authentication local credentials and there is only 1 user on the machine that is being accessed.

I am trying to get everyone that is redirected to my page authenticated automatically using this 1 user's credentials. The credentials will be accessed based on the users session existence in a database.

The IWA is configured to use NTLM.

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC? Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: I was going to use web api? Apparently IWA is the only thing they use for authentication?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you will be authenticating with Active Directory. If so, you can use ***PrincipalContext*** and ***OWIN Middleware***.

I created a sample project at GitHub called [***AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin***](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin). You can fork it and run it. *It was originally written for ASP.Net MVC, but you can use the same business logic for ASP.Net Web API too.*

There are few steps you will need to following. First of all, you want to authenticate with Active Directory.

*Note: if you use other type of authentication method, you will need to modify the logic in this class.*

```
public class ActiveDirectoryService : IActiveDirectoryService
{
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string domain, string userName, string password)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        }
    }

    public User GetUser(string domain, string userName)
    {
        User result = null;
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                result = new User
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    FirstName = user.GivenName,
                    LastName = user.Surname
                };
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Second, you want to create claims which will be used in Owin Middleware.

```
public class OwinAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
    private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

    public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SignIn(User user)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```